# Cannot submit special characters in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing an app using Codeigniter. In this app I got a form with user data.
All works fine if the user submits a form with only A-Z characters but if he is using
special characters like  ä,é,î,ø,ù the value of that field is not submitted to the controller!

This problem drives me crazy. I cannot figure out why the field is ignored? The same
field works fine with A-Z characters as said.

**Update**

In config I got: $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
I am making a POST request.

*This is my View code:*

```
    <?php echo form_open('accounts/save', 'name="theform"'); ?>

<p><?php echo form_input('firstname', null); ?></p>

<p><?php echo form_input('lastname', null); ?>

<div id="button_green">

    <a href="javascript: submitform()">Save the data</a>

</div> <!-- End of button_green -->

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Update 2**

After a looong chat with the excellent @motto and @slavic it came down to a bug
with PHP 5.3.6 (which I am using).

More information about the bug here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/261

This is the line causing the problem:

$str = @iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str);

Line: 89
File: core/utf8.php

Comment: What is your config.php $config['charset'] saying? What is the form's method (get/post) ?

Comment: $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8'; I am making a POST request.

Comment: Please add answers of these questions to your post:

What kind of hosting do you have ? 
What are the codes of your forms controller, view and model ?

Comment: Do a var_dump($_POST) in your receiving controller please.

Comment: I did a var_dump in the top of the controller and when I use A-Z the lastname is shown but when I use special characters it is not.

Comment: Output both cases please. All the content.

Comment: add model and controller please.

Comment: If I use special characters I get: array(2) { ["firstname"]=> string(4) "Adam" ["lastname"]=> string(0) "" }. If I use A-Z I get: array(2) { ["firstname"]=> string(6) "Adam" ["lastname"]=> string(4) "Bill" }

Comment: @motto. Even if I only got var_dump($_POST); in my controller and nothing else I still get the same error. Model is not even used.

Comment: interesting. paste the generated html for the form.

Comment: @motto Strange thing. If I remove UTF-8 from the config and just use $config['charset'] = ''; I get an error BUT the special characters get through to the controller! Why is that?

Comment: @JonathanClark probably you are missing something different. if you can post the whole controller and view then someone can catch what's wrong with that. i highly recommend you to share whole case.

Comment: @motto The rest of the controller code should have nothing to do with the problem because if I remove it all and only enter the var_dump() the problem remains. This is my outputted form. http://pastie.org/3206980.

Comment: @JonathanClark can you at least share your view with whole html ?

Comment: I recommend you try the same thing except write the code for the form for yourself. Then you'll be able to narrow down the problem to the accept-charset attribute, maybe.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. Just copy paste the form code from the output and I still get the same issue (http://pastie.org/3206980). It must have something to do with the UTF-8 because if I remove that from the config file it works (but I get an error).

Comment: @motto. This is my view. http://pastie.org/3206980.

Comment: have you tried the form WITHOUT the accept-charset attribute?

Comment: @slavic Unfortunately yes and the problem remains.

Comment: what browser are you trying it in?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6815/discussion-between-slavic-and-jonathan-clark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this bug report:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/261

You should use CI with different version of php. (Especially not 5.3.6)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (lowercase):

```
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
```